# Has the atomic radius been experimentally verified?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics

In the answer to a previous question it was asserted the Bohr radius was upheld by the Schrodinger wave function to be the most probable size for the atomic radius of 1s hydrogen.  Has the radius of a hydrogen atom ever been measured experimentally or is it just theory?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/how-can-we-measure-the-atomic-radius-of-an-atom

Comment: How do you define this radius? The mean radius in an ensemble of atoms? Or something else?

Comment: Basically I want to know if the Bohr radius has been verified outside of theory.

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke verified as what? A hydrogen atom with its electron in the 1s state does not have a constant radius (nor does any other atom). The electron can be found at any distance from the nucleus, but if very many measurements are made, then the most frequently observed distances will be around the Bohr radius. The Bohr radius is a useful number to simplify the math a bit and give humans an intuitive benchmark of atomic distance scales. However, it is not a universal physical constant akin to the speed of light or Planck's constant.

Comment: So has the electron been observed to be there most frequently or is it just presumed true?

Comment: I think the OP is asking if the radial probability distribution has been experimentally measured.

Answer (score 3):

The Bohr radius is a quantity that emerges from a solution of the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Hydrogen_atom) for a hydrogen atom. It gives the highest probability (not the most likely one though) to find the electron in the ground state (n=1). Use of this wave function is highly consistent with experimental results e.g. when considering the frequencies of spectral lines. If the point of highest probability would be substantially different from the Bohr radius, the obtained frequencies would be *massively* different from what is being observed.

The structure of a hydrogen atom in various states has recently actually even been 'photographed' with a 'quantum microscope' (see https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom/ ). The absolute scale of the shown pictures is here in terms of the image size, but I am sure if you would reverse engineer the imaging process, you would arrive here at the correct theoretical values as well.